# Show output of Linux commands in Web Browser - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, cgi

I am running a Python based CGI script and am having difficulties printing the output of "dig" command in a browser. I run the same script using Idle and it works.

Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

#================================================================
# Modules

import cgi
import subprocess
import re

#================================================================
# Create HTML page

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

regex_url = re.compile(r'(^https?:\/\/)(.*?)(\/.*)')

url = form.getvalue('url')
origin = form.getvalue('origin')

print ("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")

print ("<html>")
print ("<head>")
print ("<title>Lookup Tool</title>")
print ("<body>")

print ("<h1>DNS lookup tool</h1><br>")

print("<form method='post' action='/cgi-bin/test.py'>")
print("<p>Full URL including http/s: <input type='url' name='url'/></p>")
print("<p>Leave empty: <input type='text' name='origin'/></p>")
print("<input type='submit' value='Submit' />")
print("</form>")

host = regex_url.search(url)
hostname = host.group(2)

print("Hostname is: " + hostname )
resolver = subprocess.Popen(['dig', hostname], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(resolver.communication())
```

I would expect to see the output of dig www.google.com in a web browser but this is not the case. However, if I do "print(hostname)" then www.google.com would be printed in a web page.

What am I doing wrong

Comment: `dig` is a command-line utility. I don't understand by what you mean it would be printed in a web page - Do you want to use your python script to open a web browser? In this case you would have to call `subprocess.Popen` on your browser (chrome or firefox or .w.e)

Comment: @vasia but I am using "Popen". I am expecting to see this output on my web page: ; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> www.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20433
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.   IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.  254 IN A 216.58.206.36

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 10.5.13.52#53(10.5.13.52)
;; WHEN: Fri Sep 14 16:58:51 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 48

Comment: What do you mean on your *web page*?
When I ran your script as is, that was the output I got in my *terminal*

Comment: @vasia This is a CGI script, running on a Web server, so its output can appear in a browser. It's pretty old technology, but it's still ok for simple stuff.

Comment: `.communicate` returns a tuple, you need to extract the stdout data from it. OTOH, I guess you should still see *something*. Also, it's a Good Idea to send properly structured HTML: give it a `doctype`, close your `head` and `body` tags, etc.

Comment: Oh, and put that dig output in a `<pre>` block. Sorry, I don't know what else to suggest. I haven't done any CGI for a few years, and I can't play with your code because I'm on my phone.

Comment: @vasia, I have included the complete code. In the box "Full URL", please enter http://www.google.com/images/test.jpg. The name of the file in cgi-bin folder should be test.py. When you click the submit button you will see a message "Hostname is: www.google.com". What I am trying to achieve is to print the output of dig command below that text.

Comment: Try using the full path to `dig`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell unfortunately, that didn't work

Comment: I gave up at the end and decided to use Flask

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in case someone needs it in the future:

```
resolver = subprocess.Popen(['dig', hostname], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
lookup_output = resolver.communicate()[0]
lookup = 'STDOUT:{}'.format(lookup_output)
```